# not getting active directory user details after hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am not getting the Active directory user details(email,phone etc) after hosting my website in local iis (varsion5.1).  Can anyone help me?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Go to IIS

--> Right Click the Website 

--> Select Properties 

--> Select Directory Security

--> Click "Edit" in the "Authentication and access control" section.

UNCHECK Anonymous access.
CHECK Integrated Windows authentication.
CHECK Digest authentication for Windows domain servers

This solved the problem for me, hope it does the trick!

Comment: I tried that code. its working fine in Visual studio development server. But after hosting to IIS, the user name is displaying as 
ASPNET and not getting any other AD Details. I am using IIS5.1 . Please have a look on this and help me.